# $index behaves differently when used as array index

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `$index` as an index (sorry) of an array defined in the controller. It's not working, and the `$index` becomes undefined (NaNndex).

For example, this code works fine:

```
<div ng-repeat="size in size_list">
    <input ng-model="$parent.appdata.size" id="size_event_[[$index]]" type="radio" name="event_button_size" value="[[size]]" style="vertical-align: top; margin: 0 3px 0 0; left: 5px">
    <label for="size_event_[[$index]]">[[size_list[0] + '' +$index]] </label>// <----- this part works as expected
</div>
```

Now, if I change the code `[[size_list[0] + '' +$index]]` to `[[size_list[$index]]]`, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="size in size_list">
    <input ng-model="$parent.appdata.size" id="size_event_[[$index]]" type="radio" name="event_button_size" value="[[size]]" style="vertical-align: top; margin: 0 3px 0 0; left: 5px">
    <label for="size_event_[[$index]]">[[size_list[$index]]] </label>
</div>
```

it breaks, giving me this error:

Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' is unexpected, expecting []] at column null of the expression [size_list[NaNndex] starting at [{4}].

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `[[ ]]` everywhere? [Templates must be binded throught `{{ }}`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates).

You need this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <label for="{{ 'id' + '[' + $index + ']'}}">{{ item }}</label>
  <input id="{{ 'id' + '[' + $index + ']'}}" />
</div>
```

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HrPFzb2jzaOejRREG8Qb?p=preview)

Comment: Django also uses `{{` and `}}`. How do you combine without using `[[` `]]`?

Comment: You must have some hack, which define `[[ ]]` as a template, yes? Try `id="[[ 'size_event_' + $index ]]"` then. This was main point of my answer.